# Saint Quotes on Holy Obedience to Overcome Satan

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, saint, obedience, st-faustina

I have read at various times in the past regarding the devil's ability to pretend even humility, but his utter inability to feign *obedience.*

Recently, I have tried to find some quotes from Catholic Saints regarding this, but the closest thing I have been able to come up with is the following excerpt from St. Faustina's Diary (939):

> A soul that will not fully submit its inspirations to the strict control of the Church; that is, to the director, clearly shows by this that a bad spirit is guiding it. The director should be extremely prudent in such cases and test the soul's obedience. Satan can even clothe himself in a cloak of humility, but he does not know how to wear the cloak of obedience and thus his evil designs will be disclosed.

The above quote relates to spiritual direction and the obedience due thereof.

QUESTION: What quote(s) are there from other Saints regarding the weapon of obedience to overcome the devil---and Satan's utter loss to defend against it?

Answer (score 1):

How about the following quote from St. Francis de Sales:

> ``The Devil doesn’t fear austerity but holy obedience.''

See:
https://quotefancy.com/quote/1398171/Saint-Francis-de-Sales-The-Devil-doesn-t-fear-austerity-but-holy-obedience

Comment: As this is the only answer after two or three days, it gets the check mark.